# Jquery how to append class to a generated array numeric?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable that contains an array of numerics:

```
        var columnRange = []
        for (var i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
            columnRange.push(i)
        }
```

so this returns 0,1,2,3 etc until 19.

Now i'm using each of the array item to addclass to columns in the 0 - 19 range:

```
$('td:eq(' + columnRange + ')', row).addClass("Red");
```

However it does  not work as expected because **`columnRange`** contains `[0,1,2,3 etc until 19]`

How do I get a substitute for :

```
$('td:eq(0)', row).addClass("Red");
$('td:eq(2)', row).addClass("Red");
etc [long code]
```

Comment: Your array is always a continuous series without gaps? Or can it be [1,3, 8, 11,12, 22]?

Comment: You have a `for` loop, why can't you use another `for` loop to iterate the array?

Comment: @trincot my array is always a range.. no gap , always like [10 - 30]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) method:

```
$('td', row).slice(0, 20).addClass("Red");
```

Note that the second argument of `slice` is the first index *after* the range you want to select, in this example, 19 is included, 20 not.

Answer (score 0):

Not as concise as using `slice()` but you can also use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('td', row).filter(i => columnRange.includes(i)).addClass("Red");
```